# how can I know if this specific thread is still running on the server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, threadpool

I am using a thread in my ASP.Net application to be run in the backGround every 2 hours, using C#
See code below, but my question is how can I know if this specific thread is still running on the server ??
Note: I am using Windows server 2008 R2 Standard

```
 // Create runner Thread and start it 
     System.Threading.Thread OrderStatusFromThread = new       System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(OrderStatusChange));
        OrderStatusFromThread.IsBackground = true;
        OrderStatusFromThread.Name = "OrderStatusFromThread";
        OrderStatusFromThread.Start();
    }

   static void OrderStatusChange()
    {
        while (!ShutDown)
        {
          System.Threading.Thread.Sleep((1000 * 60)*10);               
          UpdateOrderStatusFromAPI();         
        }
    }
```

Comment: So you mean in your program or in an other process?

Comment: are you spawning the thread in a request?

Comment: Patrick, I mean my website is online, and I wanna check if my thread is working properly in the webserver ?
Is there a way to see the history of the thread calls in the Production server ?

Comment: Can you not determine whether it is running by checking the result of whatever it does? Do you need to do this programmatically? If not, do you have any logging that you could check?

Comment: [The Dangers of Implementing Recurring Background Tasks In ASP.NET](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/) by Phil Haack

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Join(int timeout)` function on threads.

```
if(OrderStatusFromThread.Join(1000))
{
    //Thread has terminated
}
else
{
    //Thread is still running.
}
```

Join documentation : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b1kkss0(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b1kkss0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

**Edit after new information:**

You could log the Thread's ID, or use its name, to verify with something like [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) that it is still running. Plus that tool doesn't need to be installed, it's only an exe.

Comment: Thanks Bun, but I wanna check i on the server because it is a production server. Windows 8 R2 Standard.

Comment: @MohamadElHamoui I added some info on my answer for you. If this is not enough, try posting on another StackExchange site like ServerFault where sysadmins can help you :)